# Hudson, triggers based on tagging in SVN

Tags: triggers, hudson, tagging, hudson-plugins

Is there a way or does anyone know of a plug-in that I can use so that my builds will be triggered by tagging in SVN? I have a down stream project that I want to only contain tagged versions of its up stream projects. So, if anyone knows of another possible solution to this problem, I would appreciate other suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set up a regular project with an SCM trigger that points to the SVN tags directory.

This way, it will get triggered whenever a new tag is created.